# How, when using Glob and OS, can I print Folder names and File names side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, operating-system, glob

```
    import os
    import glob

    d = os.listdir("Path")

    for folder in d:
     print(folder)

    x = glob.glob("Path/**/*.pdf")

    for files in x:
     print(files)
```

When running the first for loop, it prints the folder names within the directory.
When running the second, it prints all the .pdf file names that are within those folders.

However, when printing the file names, it also prints the directory, before the file name. How can I only print the file name and not the directory?

I also plan to have both the folder names and the corresponding file name printed side by side, and so on:
['Folder', 'File'] ['Folder', 'File'] and so on... How can I do this?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: *"One more thing"* Only one "thing" per question, sorry!

Comment: No worries. I have amended the question to be more approachable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are printing the folder is because you have two for loops.  In the first loop `for folder in d:` you are printing the folder variable.  In the second for loop `for files in x:` you are printing the files within the folder.  To do what you want, get the folders within the path, then loop through each folder and find the files, you can then print the folder and filename on the same line as shown below:

```
import os
import glob

d = os.listdir("Path")

for folder in d:
    x = glob.glob("Path/**/*.pdf")
    for file in x:
        print(f'{folder}\t{file}')
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code or commands are intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Comment: @geertjanvdk, I agree just didn't think in this case it was necessary.  I have gone back and provided more detailed explanation